# How I can check my website work in Safari mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

I have made a website that's work fine on my computer (through all modern browser). Someone reported it's not worked from Safari mobile.

I have tried to see from Safari on windows that's make me look same as I want.

I have seen their screenshot and feel something wrong with my UI. Can someone have idea how I can check the look from my computer (windows).

How I can test my website for safari mobile from my computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually download and install Safari in your computer and then check your website with all the available versions of safari for mobile. Choose Preferences->Advanced->Show developer menu in menu bar.

Finally, right click inside your website and then User Agent-> and then choose the safari version you want. [Check this link for further information](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889011/Using-Safari-for-iPhone-iPad-and-iPod-Touch-Website-Testing.htm)

Comment: Note that last Safari for windows is 5.1.7 - out in 2012

Answer (score 1):

Click "develop" on the top menu, then click on "user agent" and select your device... and navigate to your website.

Comment: this answer does not work in all cases. I have one such example currently to be solved.

Comment: This just makes the page small, but it doesn't enable touch emulation like in Chrome. How do we emulate touching (no mouse pointer)?

Comment: It may not perfectly replicate the experience, but it does do more than just resize the window. Using this method, I just discovered an overflow issue that happens only on iphone SE. So, it's definitely doing more than resizing the window.

Answer (score -1):

check this out: http://webtide.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/how-to-test-websites-for-mobile-devices/

> What you will need:
>
> Safari Testing for iPhone/iPod Touch:
>
> Open Safari and go to Preferences (Edit->Preferences).
>   Under the Advanced tab, ensure that “Show Develop menu in menu bar” is checked.
>   In the menu, click on Develop->User Agent->Mobile Safari 3.0 Browse to
>   your website and start testing!

Comment: the article written 2-3 years ago. Is their some update on that posts.

Answer (score -3):

[Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#enable-emulation-panel) has device emulation.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools doesn't correctly emulate safari behaviour. I have tested few pages and they look perfect in Chrome Dev Tools (fe. emulating iPhone 5) but on iPhones / iPads / macs looks ugly.

Comment: It emulates the screen size, not the OS.